# Target img tag within ul using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, html-lists

Say you have a set of imgs set out within a ul like this.

```
<ul>
  <li class="pic" name="pic_1_caption"><img src="abc_1.jpg" /></li>
  <li class="pic" name="pic_2_caption><img src="abc_2.jpg" /></li>
  <li class="pic" name="pic_3_caption><img src="abc_3.jpg" /></li>
<ul>
```

I can sucsessfully target a specific `img` src and `name` within the list by using.....

```
a = 0;
b = $('.pic').eq(a).attr('name');
c = $('.pic img').eq(a).attr('src');
```

....where a is the index and can change depending on which `img` I want to target.

What I can't work out is how to target just the `<img>`of the current index number list item, so that I can check to see when the `<img>` of the current index has loaded or not.

I was thinking it might look something like this.....

```
$('.pic img').eq(a).on('load' , function(){ 
    console.log('img has loaded'); 
});
```

....but not working.

Comment: you want to check if your images loaded correctly, once your page is loaded, right?

Comment: yeah that's right @charliebrownie

Comment: I don't want to loop through all the imgs in the li, but rather check to see if the img within a specific li as determined by the index has loaded or not

Comment: FYI: You have a syntax error in your third code block. `$('.pic img')` is missing the closing single quote.

Comment: Your code is fine, apart from syntax typos. See demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/f8kgbgk1/ Make sure you are attaching your event handler before the image has loaded. If you are doing it after $(document).ready it is possible the image has loaded already. You can verify this in my fiddle if you change 2nd dropdown to onLoad and rerun the fiddle - no alert.

Comment: Sweet, thanks @sifriday for fiddle and for pointing out my typos!!  At what point should I attach the even handler so that it fires before the image has loaded?

Comment: try putting the JS under the images, at the very bottom of the <body> tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [HTML5 data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/):

```
<ul>
  <li class="pic" data-loaded="false" name="pic_1_caption"/><img src="abc_1.jpg"></li>
  <li class="pic" data-loaded="false" name="pic_2_caption"/><img src="abc_2.jpg"></li>
  <li class="pic" data-loaded="false" name="pic_3_caption"/><img src="abc_3.jpg"></li>
<ul>
```

to set an attribute called `data-loaded` in each `<li>`, giving all of them a *false* value at first.

Then you can use the jquery `.load()` function to catch whenever an image is loaded inside your page. When an image is loaded in your page, you can just change the loaded image `data-loaded` value to *true* inside the `.load()` this way:

```
$( '.pic' ).find( 'img' ).load(function() {
    // Handler for .load() called.
    $( this ).parent().data( 'loaded', 'true' );
});
```

And finally, you can simply write a function that checks the `data-loaded` attribute value - given an index - this way:

```
function imageAtIndexLoaded(index) {
    return $( '.pic' ).eq( index ).data( 'loaded' );
}
```

The complete solution can be found in [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgkwhpzg/9/).

Comment: Nice one.  So because the <img> tag is html it will return true cos it's finding the img tags right?

Comment: Yes, if there's an `<img>` tag inside the requested `<li>` that function will return `true`, otherwise `false`.  If you need more info about the jQuery `.html()` method, you can find more documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: @user1563944 there was a small mistake on my function which I've just edited. Also create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgkwhpzg/2/) for you to try it!

Comment: @user1563944 hey! check the new answer, I've just edited it, now it's gonna work as you expected. Before, you checked just if there was an `<img>` tag, now you check if the image that points that tag was indeed loaded into the page. You need to use the `.load()` function to know if an image is loaded correctly or not. Please, check again the edited post - there's a fiddle example - and let me know! :-)